# NullPointerException when trying to add OnClickListener to a button

Tags: android

I'm doing the following within a Java class, NOT from within an Activity.

```
LinearLayout buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) parentContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_dialog, null);
Button btnSignIn = (Button) parentContext.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_SIGN_IN);
Button btnCancel = (Button) parentContext.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_CANCEL);
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) { ... }});
```

Layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/BTN_ID_SIGN_IN" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/em_btn_signin" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/BTN_ID_CANCEL" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/em_btn_cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The last line is throwing an NPE.  When I try my code without an onClickListener, the buttons show up perfectly (though obv nothing happens when I tap them).  Why won't it let me set anything to the button?

Comment: can you post more code? what's parentContext?

Comment: parentContext is the context of the calling Activity.  I am doing this from within a seperate class, which is not an Activity).

Comment: why do you have "null" as the second parameter of your inflate? The second parameter should be the root layout.

Comment: your buttons are inside R.layout.app_dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button btnSignIn = (Button) buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_SIGN_IN);
Button btnCancel = (Button) buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_CANCEL);
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) { ... }});
```

Answer (score 0):

What with   `btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this)` aren't you missing it?

aslo shouldn't IDs in xml be only lower case?

Comment: No, they don't have to be lower case, only the name of your xml file has to be lowercase, and there is more than one way to set an onClickListener. setOnClickListener(this) is only valid if you've implemented an internal OnClickListener class. You can also make a new instance of it the way he did instead of declaring a new internal class.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are inside R.layout.app_dialog, call:

```
Button btnSignIn = (Button) buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_SIGN_IN);
Button btnCancel = (Button) buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_CANCEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
public class className extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); 

            Button btnSignIn = (Button) buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_SIGN_IN);
            Button btnCancel = (Button) buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ID_CANCEL);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.BTN_ID_SIGN_IN:
        Intent reg = new Intent(this, Your_Next_Activity.class);
        startActivity(reg);
        finish();
        break;

    case R.id.BTN_ID_CANCEL:
        finish();
        break;

           default:break;
}
}
```

hope you ll get solve through this.

Comment: you clearly did not read the part where I said I was doing this outside of an Activity.